# SQL SERVER - Calculo

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou com uma questão para montar um painel de indicadores e que não estou conseguindo sair dela.

Basicamente tenho duas tabelas.

> Tabela 1: CONTRATOS
> Campos: ID Empresa, ID Contrato, ID Produto, Quantidade
>
> Tabela 2: RECEBIMENTOS
> Campos: ID Empresa, ID Recebimento, ID Contrato, Quantidade

Com isso montei esta query

```
SELECT
    A.ID_Empresa,
    A.ID_Produto,
    SUM(CAST(A.Quantidade AS int)) Total
 FROM 
    Contrato A
 WHERE 
    A.Registro='Ativo'
GROUP BY
    A.ID_Empresa,
    A.ID_Produto
ORDER BY
    A.ID_Empresa
```

Esta query me dá um resultado correto.

Para tentar me trazer o resultado do total recebido dos contratos montei a seguinte query.

```
SELECT
        A.ID_Empresa,
        A.ID_Produto,
        SUM(CAST(A.Quantidade AS int)) Total
     FROM 
        Contrato A
LEFT JOIN Recebimentos B ON B.ID_Contrato=A.ID_Contrato 
     WHERE 
        A.Registro='Ativo'
    GROUP BY
        A.ID_Empresa,
        A.ID_Produto
    ORDER BY
        A.ID_Empresa
```

Porém quando tento efetuar este join com a tabela RECEBIMENTOS para saber quanto foi recebido, a query está fazendo a soma da quantidade do contrato a cada vez que ele aparece na linha de recebimento.

Existe alguma forma de manter estas contas separadas e não duplicar a soma dos contratos?

Comment: Você pode escrever um exemplo dos dados das tabelas, e um exemplo do resultado esperado ?

Comment: Sim. Na primeira query meu resultado é esse:

ID Empresa | ID Produto | Total
0009   |           0000001   |  11470000
0009   |    0000002   |   800000
0012   |    0000001   |   400000
0017   |    0000001   |    4933540
0017   |    0000002   |    8000000


Porém com o join fica assim

ID Empresa    |   ID Produto    |   Total
0009    |  0000001    |  60090000
0009    |  0000002    |  800000
0012    |  0000001    |  400000
0017    |  0000001    |  62865120
0017    |  0000002    |  8000000

Comment: Minha resposta deu certo ?

Comment: Infelizmente não Marcos. Com a sua resposta a query filtrou apenas os contratos com recebimento. Eu preciso manter a conta de todos os contratos pois vou adcionar a quantidade recebida.

Comment: qual seria o resultado correto da query com join ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo o que eu entendi da sua pergunta, seria essa resposta:

```
SELECT
    A.ID_Empresa,
    A.ID_Produto,
    SUM(CAST(A.Quantidade AS int)) Total
 FROM 
    Contrato A
 WHERE 
    A.Registro='Ativo'
    AND A.ID_Contrato IN ( SELECT ID_Contrato  FROM Recebimentos  )
GROUP BY
    A.ID_Empresa,
    A.ID_Produto
ORDER BY
    A.ID_Empresa
```

Comparativo Contrato e Recebido:

```
 SELECT
    A.ID_Empresa,
    A.ID_Produto,
    SUM(CAST(A.Quantidade AS int)) AS TotalContrato,
    ValorRecebido
 FROM 
    Contrato A
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ID_Empresa,
        ID_Produto,
        SUM(CAST(Quantidade as int)) as ValorRecebido
    FROM RECEBIMENTOS
    GROUP BY
        ID_Empresa,
        ID_Produto
 ) AS B
 ON B.ID_Contrato=A.ID_Contrato 

 WHERE 
    A.Registro='Ativo'
GROUP BY
    A.ID_Empresa,
    A.ID_Produto
ORDER BY
    A.ID_Empresa
```

Comment: É que na verdade depois eu ainda preciso acrescentar uma soma do campo Quantidade só que da tabela recebimentos. Pra eu ter um comparativo entre contratado X Recebido.

Se eu fizer dessa forma, eu limito a conta a apenas os contratos que foram recebidos. Eu preciso da quantidade de todos os contratos

Comment: E agora, conseguiu o que queria ?

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado Rafael. Deu certo.
A soma estava errada porque a cardinalidade das tabelas estavam diferentes. Deixando as tabelas com a mesma cardinalidade a soma parou de duplicar. Deu muito certo. Valeu!!

Answer (score 1):

Você não colocou dados de exemplo, nem mesmo um exemplo de como seria o resultado correto, mesmo assim recriei suas tabelas no fiddle e coloquei alguns dados. Acredito que sua necessidade seja saber Quantidade Contratada / Quantidade Recebida e pelo exemplo que criei, essa query resolve seu problema. Veja:

```
   SELECT
A.ID_Empresa,
A.ID_Produto,
A.id_contrato,
SUM(CAST(A.Quantidade AS int)) TotalContratado,
sum(coalesce(r.quantidade,0)) as totalRecebido
FROM 
    Contratos A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN recebimentos r on r.id_contrato = a.id_contrato   
GROUP BY
    A.ID_Empresa,
    A.ID_Produto,
    A.id_contrato
ORDER BY
    A.ID_Empresa;
```

Veja no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/490522/2